# 12V D.C. Motor using as weight lifter

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have a weight lifter , and 12 V D.C. Motor , and want to lift a30 kg of weight , How could I use the motor to lift this weight ? Should I increase the Amp , or how!?
Thanks in advanced

Comment: So what 12V DC motor ? one form a car for the windscreen washers or perhaps one from a powered wheelchair ? You have to supply the details...

Comment: At what speed must the load be lifted?  If you lose power during operation do you want the load to fall or remain in place?

Comment: A D.C. 12 volt lift a 30kg of load from bottom to top ,  no matter what the speed was , the load remain in place

Comment: If the motor weighs more than 30kg, tie it to the other end of the string and run the string over a pulley.

Answer (score 2):

If you are applying the full 12V from a power supply that can source enough current, and it wont lift it, the motor does not have enough torque to do so.

Stop trying, you will just damage the motor.

You need to either get a bigger motor or add a gearbox or other mechanical advantage. For lifting mechanisms, it is best to use a worm gear arrangement since this will prevent the load from falling if the power goes out.

[image]

For 30kg (66lb) you may need more than a single reduction.

Comment: A starter motor may do that though, with very little gearing, granted some starters are taking 600A or more...

Comment: @SolarMike indeed a big enough motor will. Not sure a starter motor is intended to be driven for more than a few seconds though. But op never indicated the motor type so it is academic at this point.

Comment: exactly the point I made in my comment at the top...